# Some questions on enum and streamwriters vb

Tags: vb.net

Some questions i had regarding vb.net functions:

1. How do you differentiate between an enumeration and a record? As far as i'm aware an enumerated type is simply one constant with multiple identifiers and that a structure contains different data types?
2. When declared, does a variable of a structure type need to use all its fields or can some be omitted?
3. Am i correct in saying sets don't exist in vb.net and the closest thing is an arraylist?
4. Is there much of a difference in streamreaders/writers and binaryreaders/writers when referring to reading and writing to text/binary files in terms of being called and used? (Aka is the only difference the data being read? [2-3 line examples would help]
5. I'm a bit confused about transformation variables; I know that they gain their value from the fixed calculation of another variable, but i can't seem to gain an understanding of it.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer, if these were posed separately; it would also be good to see how far you've got with your own research on them, too.

Comment: Sorry for asking so many simple questions, i've pretty much written down my understanding from my research down with the questions i've asked. Sorry if I am wasting time, I have looked these up to only ask essential questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you differentiate between an enumeration and a record?

In what context? Basically an [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.enum%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a list of constants and can be used pretty much anywhere.  Records mainly have to do with Databases and Datasets, which means a record could be made up of any data types

> As far as i'm aware an enumerated type is simply one constant with multiple
>   identifiers and that a structure contains different data types?

A [structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k69kzbs1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is basically a way of organizing a certain set of variables.

> When declared, does a variable of a structure type need to use all its
>   fields or can some be omitted?

Every field is part of the structure when it is declared.

> Am i correct in saying sets don't exist in vb.net and the closest
>   thing is an arraylist?

Not sure what you mean by set.  .net contains classes for several different types of [collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a1y8b3b3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), of which arraylist is just one.

> Is there much of a difference in streamreaders/writers and
>   binaryreaders/writers when referring to reading and writing to
>   text/binary files in terms of being called and used?

Basically the main difference is that because binary doesn't normally include line breaks, that method uses buffers, where as text readers use strings and recognize line breaks.

> I'm a bit confused about transformation variables; I know that they
>   gain their value from the fixed calculation of another variable, but i
>   can't seem to gain an understanding of it.

Not really sure what you're getting at here. I suspect that that has to do with higher math functions and not really .net specific.